# What is the appropriate site for asking a "building VMware-workstation on Rocky Linux" question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is the appropriate site for asking a "building [VMware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware)-workstation on [Rocky Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Linux)" question?

I have searched for rocky and VMware, with no matches on the general form, so I have not bothered to try the more specific terms "rocky-linux" and "VMware-workstation".

Rocky Linux does not appear to have a site, nor does "vmware-workstation".

Comment: Within the Stack Exchange network, I might check the Help Centers for [unix.se] and [su] to see whether your question would be considered on-topic on either of those sites.

Comment: Most Linux distributions are derived from some other Linux distribution. If they are sufficiently close it *might* work for the *parent* Linux distribution instead (or grandparent).

Answer (score 2):

On-topic on both https://superuser.com and https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Tags:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vmware-workstation
- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vmware-workstation